# Rollover in Fireworks without slice tool

Tags: website-design, cs5, adobe-fireworks, actions

I want to create an imagemap in Fireworks CS5 on which certain parts shall change when I roll over with the mouse. These parts shall contain links to a new website as well!

Since I am using a photograph, I need to be very precise with my rollover parts. It looks to me though that I only can use the slice tool to create roll overs, not the tool where I can create Polygons (left to the slice tool, with that light blue when drawn).

If so, is there a way around? It would be a shame if rollovers only can be created on rectangular shapes...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images (PNG, GIF, JPG, etc) are always rectangular. So if the intent is to make image-based rollovers, yes, they would be rectangular.

Options:

- create an image map for each image that triggers the rollover
- use one large image, with each image map region triggering a swap of the overall image

Note that while image maps still have their place, these tend to be rather antiquated solutions in a lot of cases--especially using FW's generated code to handle it. It might be easier to use CSS or a JS library to handle it these days.

UPDATE:

Based on your comment, here's one way to accomplish your goal:

Let's say the class photo has 10 people in it. What you need is to create 11 versions of this image. One 'as-is' then 10 with each individual person highlighted.

Now you can apply an image map using any shapes you want around each face. Upon each roll-over of that hot-spot, you now need to swap out the entire background image to make it look like that one head is being highlighted.

The drawback here, of course, is that you have to load 11 images--which may not be practical in terms of speed and bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. Bummer that rollovers only work on rectangular shapes. Imagen one has a circle and want to add a rollover effect to that...

The aim is something like this. Imagine having a classfoto with a lot of people. rolling with mouse over each person, I want the person to "shine" or be highlighted and to be clickable. So clicking on the person shall open a new pop up.

I never did something like this with CSS or JS. Its been a long time since I worked in Webdesign and related subjects. Where would I find something like this?

Comment: @Maccaroni I've updated my answer with more specifics.

Comment: thanks for your update. I might go with the JS library. I just had a look at it and it does not seem to be too complicated. Furthermore, it should be easy to implement the JS imagemap into Joomla! And, if further editing is needed, it seems easier to accomplish.